# Перевод сообщения в профиле о постах на других сайтах SO - "Мы уважаем сосредоточенность на одной тематике"

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, профиль-участника

Заглянул в [профиль](/users/239760/eranewgames) и увидел:

[image: скриншот]

Собственно, что это??? Может, поменяем текст?

PS: Кажется, пока писал вопрос, до меня дошёл смысл фразы. У пользователя нет сообщений на других сайтах, т. е. он писал их только тут, а мы это как бы уважаем.
**Всё равно предлагаю поменять.**

Comment: Ты меня уважаешь? Да! А ты меня? Тоже! Да мы с тобой уважаемые люди!

Comment: В оригинале: *We respect a laser-like focus on one topic.* Смысл, на мой взгляд, сохранён.

Comment: @D-side: В русском языке «уважаем» — это скорее «одобряем», чем «считаем, что и так сойдёт».

Comment: Ваше собственное предложение будет озвучено?

Comment: @alexolut, не получилось его придумать...

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаю следующий вариант, прямой и честный:

> #### Лучшие сообщения сети
>
> Интересных сообщений в других сообществах нет.

Не считаю нужным дополнительно это оправдывать и смягчать, т. к. это действует и в обратную сторону: создаёт у участников ощущение, что к этому нужно относиться плохо.

---

Давайте вообще забьём на исходную фразу и **изучим, к чему она относится**, а на основе этого сформируем новый вариант.

Критерии, [судя по мета-мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254477/318749), для сообщений в этом списке следующие:

- Первые сообщения по убыванию рейтинга
- Рейтинг не меньше 5
- Не относятся к закрытым и дубликатам (и не являются ими)
- Являются авторскими (не общими)
- Опубликованы не на том сайте, где просматривается профиль

Обратите внимание, что когда список пуст:

- Не факт, что пользователь что-то публиковал на **этом** сайте
- Не факт, что у него вообще нет сообщений на других сайтах

Этот список показывает не только лучшие сообщения участника, но и их пересечение с хорошими сообщениями в целом. А если их нет... ну нет и нет.

Comment: Вроде бы для отражения интереса на SO принято использовать термин "популярный".

Comment: Ну и "интересный", имхо, более субъективный показатель, нежели "популярный".

Comment: @alexolut так добавьте ещё вариант новым ответом =)

Comment: Ну ладно, если будут минусовать, сошлюсь на Вас :)

Answer (score 5):

<s>Генно-</s>модифицированный [вариант @D-side](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5723/176217):

> Популярных сообщений в других сообществах нет.

Comment: Этот вариант не намного хуже, чем "интересных", но явно хуже. Популярность -- это что-то, что имеет отношение к толпе, дешёвой славе поп-звёзд и т.п. Интерес бывает научно-исследовательским, слово "интерес" ближе к слову "любопытство". Проголосовал здесь в минус, а в "интересный" - в плюс.

Comment: Прилагательное "популярный" уже достаточно много где используется на сайте применительно к сообщениям. И отражает общую тенденцию сообщества. А вот "интересный" - это индивидуальная оценка. Т.е. если вы ставите +1, пост вам интересен, но это ещё не значит, что он будет интересен другим и в итоге достаточно популярен, чтобы попасть в список "лучшие сообщения сети".

Comment: Почему бы тогда не использовать вместо "популярный" вариант "хороший"? Используется имху более широко ("хороший вопрос", "хороший ответ", популярный сходу не могу вспомнить, но допускаю, что также достаточно много где встречается) и не имеет негативных призвуков, как "популярный".

Comment: @AK хороший ответ может быть с 0-вым количеством голосов за, так что ваш вариант мне нравится меньше

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, английский вариант - это ирония. Во всех предложенных "трансляциях" на русский подобная ирония отсутствует. Не в укор переводчикам, но тем не менее.

Как насчёт

> Мы не против узкой специализации

или чего-то подобного?

Comment: Интересная мысль, но у меня не соотносится такая фраза с заголовком. Есть заголовок "Лучшие сообщения сети" и тут вдруг мы что-то уважаем или не против... Возникает смысловой диссонанс, а при чём тут собственно лучшие сообщения.

Answer (score -2):

Так как сеть Stack Exchange - это в большинстве своём множество англоязычных сайтов различных тематик, и о их существовании англоязычному пользователю обычно сразу становится известно (просто потому, что текст понятен), то русскоязычному это не сразу становится очевидным. Текущий вариант перевода может вводить в состояние легкого ступора (со мной тоже такое было). И пока русскоязычных сайтов не будет достаточно много, текущая версия перевода будет продолжать обескураживать. Чтобы этого не происходило следует использовать более однозначную формулировку. Например, такую:

> Участник недостаточно активен в других сообществах

Фраза может быть другой, но главный посыл в том, чтобы она была максимально очевидной.

Comment: ваш вариант `недостаточно активен в других сообществах` наталкивает на мысль об ограничении функционала (не только того, о котором сейчас идет речь) из-за того пользователь не стал участником другого сообщества

Comment: "недостаточно активен в других сообществах" недостаточно для чего? Меня полностью устраивает текущий вариант сообщения, т.к. он нейтрален.

Comment: @FoggyFinder ограничение участия - да, но функционала? Какого?

Comment: @GreenDragon для того, чтобы можно было называть сообщения из других сообществ "лучшими". Можно написать множество сообщений с нулевым рейтингом и они не попадут в этот список. Хотя человек и будет участником сообщества.

Comment: @alexolut возможность видеть сообщения сети

Comment: @FoggyFinder информация в профиле относится к владельцу профиля, а не к тому, кто его просматривает. В частности поэтому там "участник", а не "вы".

Comment: @alexolut не пойму зачем вы мне это пишите, ваш комментарий больше подходит к ответу VladD

Comment: @FoggyFinder в контексте нашего диалога он не менее уместен. Вы же считаете, что моя формулировка говорит об ограничении возможностей, я объясняю почему это не так. Или я Вам неправильно понял?

Comment: @alexolut о том и речь, что формулировка должна быть ясна без дополнительных пояснений

Comment: @FoggyFinder вот поэтому и предложение возникло, так как существующая формулировка недостаточно ясна. Но Вам кажется иначе, как я понял.

Comment: правильно :) btw, забавно видеть столько минусов, хотя

Comment: @FoggyFinder такой вот be-nice! :-D

Answer (score -3):

Оставить как есть, так как такой вариант перевода кажется достаточно удачным

Comment: Это только кажется!

Comment: @alexolut не мне одному ;p

Comment: Из всех ответов только 2 перевода - с аналогичным положительным окрасом, как в оригинале. Остальные - негативные. Думаю, суть была именно в этом.

Answer (score -3):

Калька — это всегда ужасно. Давайте подберём адекватный перевод.

Поскольку безличная конструкция выглядит костылём для отсутствия разницы в локализации для своего профиля и профилей других участников, необходимо сделать такое разделение (на уровне движка), и использовать два варианта фразы. Например:

> Вся ваша репутация заработана на одном сайте. И это тоже неплохо.

и

> Вся репутация этого участника заработана на одном сайте. И это тоже неплохо.

Comment: Почему бы использовать единый вариант "Вся репутация участника заработана на одном сайте. И это тоже неплохо."?

Comment: Калька — это не всегда ужасно.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Практически всегда. Калька = лень переводчика. В живой, настоящей речи люди не пользуются калькой.

Comment: @alexolut: Можно и так, напишете отдельным вариантом? Но это на мой взгляд всё равно хуже, чем два варианта, т. к. читать про себя в третьем лице странно.

Comment: Не. Меня что-то минусуют :) Пишите сами. Вообще, надо @Qwertiy заставить кашу расхлёбывать.

Comment: @alexolut: Меня больше минусуют :-) У вас в сумме -2, у меня -3!

Comment: Есть ещё @FoggyFinder

Comment: @alexolut: Ну он-то против изменений.

Comment: @alexolut: Добавил и этот вариант.

Answer (score -3):

> Всё лучшее на этом сайте!

Можно ещё чем-то дополнить, но может и так неплохо?

Comment: Какой-то рекламный пафос. Сразу вызывает отторжение и желание отправить нафиг.

Comment: Можно ещё добавить "... поэтому больше никуда не ходите!"

Comment: @AK, просто надо смотреть вместе с заголовком: "Лучшие сообщения сети" ;)

Answer (score -5):

Например, такой вариант:

> Вы пишете только на одном сайте, и это тоже неплохо

Comment: Там какая-то завязка еще на рейтинг видимо, так как сообщение выводится даже при участии на нескольких сайтах. Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/209956/cheg (на enSO есть один ответ).

Comment: Обращение "Вы" в данном случае не совсем уместно, т.к. текст видит любой участник, а не только владелец аккаунта.

Comment: @alexolut: Хм, это хуже. А разделить на свой/не свой акк нельзя?

Comment: только если изменениями в движке, чтобы строки разделить.

Comment: @VladD, увидел Ваши заминусованные сообщения. Теперь можно и на покой, ибо видел всё :)

Answer (score -5):

Альтернативный [вариант от @alexolut](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5708/5720#comment21752_5719):

> Вся репутация заработана на одном сайте. И это тоже неплохо.

Плюс в том, что не нужна переделка движка.

Comment: На самом деле, это неправда. Так как есть порог репутации (судя по всему), то не обязательно вся репутация будет на одном сайте. На другом она тоже может быть, в незначительном кол-ве.

Comment: @alexolut: Тогда правьте.